# GoogleTokenResponse is not executing..!

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to make an application that is supposed to work on devices that doesn't have Play Services installed. Currently I'm on login, using webview. I have successfully received an authorization code here, & to retrive access token, I am using following snippet, (from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest)

Somehow, on GoogleTokenResponse , appplication crashes at `.execute()`... What  I am supposed to change here?

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (url.startsWith(OAuth2Client.REDIRECT_URI)) {
                    try {
                        if (url.indexOf("code=") != -1) {
                            String code = extractCodeFromUrl(url);

                            try {
                                GoogleTokenResponse response =
                                        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                                                OAuth2Client.CLIENT_ID, OAuth2Client.CLIENT_SECRET,
                                                code, OAuth2Client.REDIRECT_URI)
                                                .execute();                                                                  //debugging stops here!!
                                System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
                            } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
                                if (e.getDetails() != null) {
                                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
                                    if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
                                        System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
                                    }
                                    if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
                                        System.err.println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }


                        } else if (url.indexOf("error=") != -1) {
                            OAuth2Client.ClearAccessToken(getApplicationContext());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("onPageFinished : " + url);
            }
```

Comment: I would first add a catch block to catch `Exception` and try to find out which Exception is raised.

Comment: nothing happens, is just crashes without any log